# Debian: How to get rid of half-installed packages after aborted installation of kde-standard?

Tags: debian, apt

I accidentally executed "apt-get install kde-standard" on a system with a very small root partition (6 GB). The installation stopped when the disk was full. You can imagine the mess I have on the system now.
apt-get * says: "301 not fully installed or removed."

Is there a way to remove all packages that came with kde-standard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
apt-get purge kde-standard
apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: I don't know. I had to manually purge packages that were not configured to get kde-standard removed. And when I execute apt-get autoremove, it removes nothing.

Comment: You're sure that packages still remain? What happens if you do `apt-get -s install kde-standard` (to simulate it). Does it install less than the first time?

Comment: In my case your solution didn't work for me because of all the half-installed packages. But I accept your answer as the solution, because it should work this way and I'm happy that somebody answered here :)

Answer (score 0):

So, while there are better ways to do this, this one worked for me: set up a new machine (debian wheezy), run

```
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install kde-standard
```

then copy the list of 748 packages and remove them on the first machine. Looks like this:

```
apt-get purge acl akonadi-backend-mysql akonadi-server akregator ark aspell aspell-en binutils colord consolekit cpp cpp-4.7 crda     cryptsetup-bin dbus dbus-x11 dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service dnsmasq-base docbook-xml docbook-xsl dolphin dosfstools  dragonplayer enchant fontconfig fontconfig-config fonts-droid fonts-freefont-ttf freespacenotifier fuse gconf-service gconf2  gconf2-common ghostscript gnupg-agent gnupg2 gsfonts gwenview hdparm hicolor-icon-theme htdig hunspell-en-us imagemagick  imagemagick-common iw juk kaddressbook kamera kate kate-data katepart kcalc kde-baseapps kde-baseapps-bin kde-baseapps-data  kde-plasma-desktop kde-runtime kde-runtime-data kde-standard kde-style-oxygen kde-wallpapers kde-wallpapers-default  kde-window-manager kde-workspace kde-workspace-bin kde-workspace-data kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins kdebase-runtime  kdelibs-bin kdelibs5-data kdelibs5-plugins kdepasswd kdepim-runtime kdepimlibs-kio-plugins kdeplasma-addons kdm kdoctools  kfind khelpcenter4 kinfocenter klipper kmail kmenuedit kmix knotes konq-plugins konqueror konqueror-nsplugins konsole kopete  korganizer kscreensaver kscreensaver-xsavers ksnapshot ksysguard ksysguardd kwalletmanager kwrite liba52-0.7.4 libaa1  libaacs0 libaio1 libakonadi-contact4 libakonadi-kabc4 libakonadi-kcal4 libakonadi-kde4 libakonadi-kmime4  libakonadiprotocolinternals1 libarchive12 libasound2 libaspell15 libass4 libassuan0 libasyncns0 libatasmart4 libatk1.0-0  libatk1.0-data libattica0 libaudio2 libaudit0 libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libavc1394-0  libavcodec53 libavformat53 libavutil51 libbluetooth3 libbluray1 libboost-program-options1.49.0 libcaca0 libcairo-gobject2  libcairo2 libcanberra-gtk3-0 libcanberra-gtk3-module libcanberra0 libcddb2 libcdio13 libck-connector0 libcln6 libclucene0ldbl  libcolord1 libcroco3 libcryptsetup4 libcrystalhd3 libcups2 libcupsimage2 libcurl3-gnutls libdatrie1 libdbus-1-3  libdbus-glib-1-2 libdbusmenu-qt2 libdc1394-22 libdca0 libdconf0 libdevmapper-event1.02.1 libdirac-decoder0 libdirac-encoder0  libdirectfb-1.2-9 libdjvulibre-text libdjvulibre21 libdlrestrictions1 libdmtx0a libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau1a libdrm-radeon1  libdrm2 libdvbpsi7 libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 libebml3 libenca0 libenchant1c2a libencode-locale-perl libexif12 libexiv2-12  libfaad2 libfam0 libffi5 libfile-basedir-perl libfile-copy-recursive-perl libfile-desktopentry-perl libfile-listing-perl  libfile-mimeinfo-perl libflac8 libfont-afm-perl libfontconfig1 libfontenc1 libfribidi0 libgadu3 libgconf-2-4 libgd2-xpm  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgif4 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libgle3 libglib2.0-0  libglib2.0-data libglu1-mesa libgmp10 libgomp1 libgpgme++2 libgphoto2-2 libgphoto2-l10n libgphoto2-port0 libgps20 libgs9  libgs9-common libgsm1 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 libgstreamer0.10-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libgtk2.0-0  libgtk2.0-bin libgtk2.0-common libgudev-1.0-0 libgusb2 libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl libhtml-parser-perl  libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-tree-perl libhttp-cookies-perl libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl  libhttp-negotiate-perl libhunspell-1.3-0 libical0 libice6 libieee1284-3 libijs-0.35 libilmbase6 libimobiledevice2  libio-socket-ip-perl libio-socket-ssl-perl libiodbc2 libiso9660-8 libjasper1 libjbig0 libjbig2dec0 libjim0debian2  libjpeg-progs libjpeg8 libjson0 libkabc4 libkactivities-bin libkactivities6 libkate1 libkateinterfaces4  libkatepartinterfaces4 libkcal4 libkcalcore4 libkcalutils4 libkcmutils4 libkde3support4 libkdeclarative5 libkdecorations4  libkdecore5 libkdepim4 libkdesu5 libkdeui5 libkdewebkit5 libkdnssd4 libkemoticons4 libkephal4abi1 libkexiv2-10 libkexiv2-data  libkfile4 libkholidays4 libkhtml5 libkidletime4 libkimap4 libkimproxy4 libkio5 libkipi-data libkipi8 libkjsapi4 libkjsembed4  libkldap4 libkleo4 libkmediaplayer4 libkmime4 libknewstuff2-4 libknewstuff3-4 libknotifyconfig4 libkntlm4 libkonq-common  libkonq5-templates libkonq5abi1 libkonqsidebarplugin4a libkontactinterface4 libkopete4 libkparts4 libkpgp4 libkpimidentities4  libkpimtextedit4 libkpimutils4 libkprintutils4 libkpty4 libkresources4 libkrosscore4 libksba8 libkscreensaver5 libksgrd4  libksieve4 libksignalplotter4 libktexteditor4 libktnef4 libkunitconversion4 libkutils4 libkwineffects1abi3 libkwinglutils1  libkworkspace4abi1 liblcms1 liblcms2-2 liblensfun-data liblensfun0 liblircclient0 liblqr-1-0 libltdl7 liblua5.1-0  liblvm2app2.2 liblwp-mediatypes-perl liblwp-protocol-https-perl liblzo2-2 libmad0 libmagickcore5 libmagickcore5-extra  libmagickwand5 libmailtools-perl libmailtransport4 libmarblewidget13 libmatroska5 libmeanwhile1 libmediastreamer1  libmessagecore4 libmessagelist4 libmhash2 libmicroblog4 libmimelib4 libmng1 libmodplug1 libmozjs10d libmp3lame0 libmpc2  libmpcdec6 libmpeg2-4 libmpfr4 libmsn0.3 libmtdev1 libmtp-common libmtp-runtime libmtp9 libmysqlclient18 libnepomuk4  libnepomukquery4a libnepomukutils4 libnet-dbus-perl libnet-http-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libnetfilter-conntrack3 libnetpbm10  libnettle4 libnl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-200 libnl-route-3-200 libnm-glib-vpn1 libnm-glib4 libnm-util2 libnotify4 libnspr4  libntrack-qt4-1 libntrack0 libogg0 libokularcore1 libopenexr6 libopenjpeg2 liborc-0.4-0 libortp8 libotr2 libpam-ck-connector  libpango1.0-0 libpaper-utils libpaper1 libparted0debian1 libpcap0.8 libpciaccess0 libpcsclite1 libphonon4 libpixman-1-0  libpkcs11-helper1 libplasma-geolocation-interface4 libplasma3 libplasmaclock4abi3 libplasmagenericshell4 libplist1 libpng12-0  libpolkit-agent-1-0 libpolkit-backend-1-0 libpolkit-gobject-1-0 libpolkit-qt-1-1 libpoppler-qt4-3 libpoppler19 libpostproc52  libprison0 libprocesscore4abi1 libprocessui4a libproxy0 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 libpython2.7 libqalculate5  libqalculate5-data libqca2 libqca2-plugin-ossl libqgpgme1 libqimageblitz4 libqrencode3 libqt4-dbus libqt4-declarative  libqt4-designer libqt4-help libqt4-network libqt4-opengl libqt4-qt3support libqt4-script libqt4-scripttools libqt4-sql  libqt4-sql-mysql libqt4-sql-sqlite libqt4-svg libqt4-test libqt4-xml libqt4-xmlpatterns libqtassistantclient4 libqtcore4  libqtdbus4 libqtgui4 libqtlocation1 libqtruby4shared2 libqtwebkit4 libraptor2-0 librasqal3 libraw1394-11 librdf0 libreadline5  libresid-builder0c2a librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common librtmp0 libruby1.8 libsamplerate0 libsane libsane-common libsane-extras  libsane-extras-common libschroedinger-1.0-0 libsdl-image1.2 libsdl1.2debian libsensors4 libsgutils2-2 libshout3 libsidplay2  libsm6 libsmbclient libsmokebase3 libsmokekdecore4-3 libsmokekdeui4-3 libsmokekfile3 libsmokekhtml3 libsmokekio3  libsmokeknewstuff2-3 libsmokeknewstuff3-3 libsmokekparts3 libsmokektexteditor3 libsmokekutils3 libsmokenepomuk3  libsmokeplasma3 libsmokeqtcore4-3 libsmokeqtdbus4-3 libsmokeqtgui4-3 libsmokeqtnetwork4-3 libsmokeqtopengl4-3  libsmokeqtsql4-3 libsmokeqtsvg4-3 libsmokeqtwebkit4-3 libsmokeqtxml4-3 libsmokesolid3 libsndfile1 libsocket-perl libsolid4  libsolidcontrol4abi2 libsolidcontrolifaces4abi2 libsoprano4 libspandsp2 libspectre1 libspeex1 libspeexdsp1 libsrtp0 libssh-4  libssh2-1 libstreamanalyzer0 libstreams0 libswscale2 libsyndication4 libsystemd-login0 libtag1-vanilla libtag1c2a libtalloc2  libtar0 libtaskmanager4abi3 libtdb1 libthai-data libthai0 libtheora0 libthreadweaver4 libtidy-0.99-0 libtie-ixhash-perl  libtiff4 libtimedate-perl libts-0.0-0 libtwolame0 libupnp6 libupower-glib1 liburi-perl libusbmuxd1 libutempter0 libv4l-0  libv4lconvert0 libva-x11-1 libva1 libvcdinfo0 libvirtodbc0 libvlc5 libvlccore5 libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2 libvorbisfile3  libvpx1 libwbclient0 libweather-ion6 libwebp2 libwmf0.2-7 libwww-perl libwww-robotrules-perl libx11-protocol-perl libx11-xcb1  libx264-123 libx86-1 libxaw7 libxcb-composite0 libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-keysyms1 libxcb-randr0 libxcb-render0  libxcb-shape0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb-util0 libxcb-xfixes0 libxcb-xv0 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxfixes3 libxfont1  libxft2 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxkbfile1 libxml-parser-perl libxml-twig-perl libxml-xpathengine-perl libxml2-utils libxmu6  libxpm4 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxslt1.1 libxss1 libxt6 libxtst6 libxv1 libxvidcore4 libxvmc1 libxxf86dga1 libxxf86vm1  libyajl2 libzvbi-common libzvbi0 lockfile-progs marble-data marble-plugins mobile-broadband-provider-info modemmanager  mysql-common mysql-server-core-5.5 netpbm network-manager network-manager-openvpn network-manager-pptp network-manager-vpnc  notification-daemon ntfs-3g ntrack-module-libnl-0 odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 okular openvpn oxygen-icon-theme oxygencursors  p7zip-full phonon phonon-backend-vlc pinentry-gtk2 plasma-containments-addons plasma-dataengines-addons  plasma-dataengines-workspace plasma-desktop plasma-desktopthemes-artwork plasma-runners-addons plasma-scriptengine-javascript  plasma-scriptengine-python plasma-scriptengine-ruby plasma-scriptengine-superkaramba plasma-scriptengine-webkit  plasma-scriptengines plasma-wallpapers-addons plasma-widget-folderview plasma-widget-lancelot plasma-widget-networkmanagement  plasma-widgets-addons plasma-widgets-workspace pm-utils policykit-1 polkit-kde-1 poppler-data powermgmt-base ppp pptp-linux  python-dbus python-dbus-dev python-kde4 python-qt4 python-qt4-dbus python-sip qdbus ruby-kde4 ruby-plasma ruby-qt4  ruby-qt4-webkit ruby1.8 sane-utils sgml-data shared-desktop-ontologies shared-mime-info soprano-daemon sweeper systemsettings  tsconf ttf-dejavu ttf-dejavu-core ttf-dejavu-extra udisks ufraw-batch unzip update-inetd upower usb-modeswitch  usb-modeswitch-data usbmuxd vbetool virtuoso-minimal virtuoso-opensource-6.1-bin virtuoso-opensource-6.1-common vlc vlc-data  vlc-nox vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-pulse vpnc wireless-regdb wpasupplicant x11-common x11-utils x11-xkb-utils  x11-xserver-utils xbitmaps xdg-utils xfonts-base xfonts-encodings xfonts-utils xscreensaver-data xscreensaver-data-extra  xscreensaver-gl xscreensaver-gl-extra xscreensaver-screensaver-bsod xserver-common xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core  xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-mouse xserver-xorg-input-synaptics  xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-video-apm xserver-xorg-video-ark  xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-chips xserver-xorg-video-cirrus xserver-xorg-video-fbdev xserver-xorg-video-i128  xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-mach64 xserver-xorg-video-mga xserver-xorg-video-neomagic  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-openchrome xserver-xorg-video-r128 xserver-xorg-video-radeon  xserver-xorg-video-rendition xserver-xorg-video-s3 xserver-xorg-video-s3virge xserver-xorg-video-savage  xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion xserver-xorg-video-sis xserver-xorg-video-sisusb xserver-xorg-video-tdfx  xserver-xorg-video-trident xserver-xorg-video-tseng xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware  xserver-xorg-video-voodoo xterm zip
```

After that call

```
apt-get autoremove
```

System is free again.

Comment: That's a lot of effort :). You could have just gotten an approximation and ask me for a list of packages that would have been installed if I had installed kde-standard on a Debian machine. I have enough to test on.

Comment: (caution, shameless advertisement for my provider) well, I'm using profitbricks.com and starting a machine with debian needs 5-10 minutes, so this was the simplest and cheapest way for me.

Comment: be aware that while doing this you may end up removing (and purging the configuration files for!) more than you intended to.